# How to merge elements together

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a class that represents an Employee and it has an id and other employees who report to them.

```
class Employee {
   int val;
   ArrayList<Employee> sub;
}
```

Now I have these employees in form of a tree structure:

```
      4
     / \ 
   /    \
  3      6
 / \     /|\
2  4    5 8 1
```

Now I want to find out the manager and number of employees who report to them in the form of a map where key is the manager and value as list of employees who report to them.

```
Example:

4 -> 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 8, 1
3 -> 2, 4
6 -> 5, 8, 1
```

The input to my program is the top-level element in the above tree which is with id = 4.

```
Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> process(Employee topEmployee) {

}
```

**Update:**

Writing code based on sodrul solution:

```
public static void processRecursively(Employee topEmployee, Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap) {
    if (topEmployee.sub == null || topEmployee.sub.size() == 0)
        return;
    ArrayList<Employee> subList = resultMap.get(topEmployee);
    if (subList == null) {
        subList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultMap.put(topEmployee, subList);
    }
    for (Employee employee : topEmployee.sub) {
        if (!subList.contains(employee)) {
            subList.add(employee);
        }
    }
    for (Employee employee : topEmployee.sub) {
        processRecursively(employee, resultMap);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee topEmployee = new Employee(4);
    topEmployee.sub = new ArrayList<>();

    Employee e3 = new Employee(3);
    e3.sub = new ArrayList<>();

    Employee e6 = new Employee(6);
    e6.sub = new ArrayList<>();

    Employee e2 = new Employee(2);
    e2.sub = new ArrayList<>();
    Employee e4 = new Employee(4);
    e4.sub = new ArrayList<>();

    Employee e5 = new Employee(5);
    e5.sub = new ArrayList<>();
    Employee e8 = new Employee(8);
    e8.sub = new ArrayList<>();
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1);
    e1.sub = new ArrayList<>();

    topEmployee.sub.add(e3);
    topEmployee.sub.add(e6);

    e3.sub.add(e2);
    e3.sub.add(e4);

    e6.sub.add(e5);
    e6.sub.add(e8);
    e6.sub.add(e1);

    Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    processRecursively(topEmployee, resultMap);

    resultMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println("key=" + k.val);
        System.out.println("child count : " + v.size());
        v.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.print(e.val + " ");
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
}

static class Employee {
    public int val;
    public ArrayList<Employee> sub;

    public Employee() {
        sub = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Employee(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.sub = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee $val=" + val + ", sub=" + sub + "#";
    }

}
```

Output for this program is:

```
key=6
child count : 3
5 8 1 

key=4
child count : 2
3 6 

key=3
child count : 2
2 4
```

For employee with val as 4, the children should be 3,6,2,4,5,8,1 . It means it has 7 children. but the above logs shows it has only 2 children.

Comment: @Eritrean, yes my mistake, im removing that word binary

Comment: This looks like Breadth-first search (BFS) There are quite a lot of tutorials that can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tree doesn't have any loop in it, then below code would do. Easiest way I could find is to use recursion.

```
public static void processRecursively(Employee topEmployee, Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap) {
        if(topEmployee.sub == null || topEmployee.sub.size() == 0)
            return;
        ArrayList<Employee> subList = resultMap.get(topEmployee);
        if(subList == null){
            subList = new ArrayList<>();
            resultMap.put(topEmployee, subList);
        }
        for(Employee employee: topEmployee.sub){
            if(!subList.contains(employee)){
                subList.add(employee);
            }
        }
        for(Employee employee: topEmployee.sub){
            processRecursively(employee, resultMap);
        }
    }
```

You call it from top level

```
Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
processRecursively(topEmployee, resultMap);
```

Result will be saved in `resultMap`. I have used BFS algorithm here.

**NOTE: If your tree has any loop then it may result in an infinity loop.**

**EDIT:** According to the comment of @learner. To achieve the list of all the employees under the root or any other super node, the traverse must be changed to post-order. It will traverse and add all the child from leaf first. Then recursively add bottom-up manner. The code would look like this.

```
public static void processRecursively(Employee topEmployee, Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap) {
    if(topEmployee.sub == null || topEmployee.sub.size() == 0)
        return;
    ArrayList<Employee> subList = resultMap.get(topEmployee);
    if(subList == null){
        subList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultMap.put(topEmployee, subList);
    }

    for(Employee employee: topEmployee.sub){
        processRecursively(employee, resultMap);
    }

    for(Employee employee: topEmployee.sub){
        if(!subList.contains(employee)){
            subList.add(employee);
        }
        if(employee.sub != null && employee.sub.size() > 0) {
            for(Employee e: employee.sub) {
                if(!subList.contains(e))
                    subList.add(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, but it is not giving me the expected results `4 -> 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 8, 1`, I have updated my question with details. please check. Also, I don't have any loops in my code to result in infinity.

Comment: I have edited the method. So as your requirement the we should traverse the tree with post-order traversal. Can you check again with new method.

Comment: The `subList.contains(e)` part adds unnecessary complexity. It can be done in O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a post order traversal of the tree to get the result you need. In a [post order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order,_LRN) you first visit all the children and then the parent node. So when you visit the node you already have everything that is available at the child nodes that you can use to build the map.

The code would be :

```
    public static void postOrder(Employee top, Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> map) {
        if ( top == null ) {
            return;
        }
        
        for ( Employee child : top.sub ) {
            postOrder(child, map);
        }
        
        ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(top.sub);
        for ( Employee child : top.sub ) {
           list.addAll(map.containsKey(child) ? map.get(child) : new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.put(top, list);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee topEmployee = new Employee(4);
        topEmployee.sub = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee e3 = new Employee(3);
        e3.sub = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee e6 = new Employee(6);
        e6.sub = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee e2 = new Employee(2);
        e2.sub = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4);
        e4.sub = new ArrayList<>();

        Employee e5 = new Employee(5);
        e5.sub = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e8 = new Employee(8);
        e8.sub = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1);
        e1.sub = new ArrayList<>();

        topEmployee.sub.add(e3);
        topEmployee.sub.add(e6);

        e3.sub.add(e2);
        e3.sub.add(e4);

        e6.sub.add(e5);
        e6.sub.add(e8);
        e6.sub.add(e1);

        Map<Employee, ArrayList<Employee>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
//      processRecursively(topEmployee, resultMap);
        postOrder(topEmployee, resultMap);

        resultMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if ( v.size() > 0 ) {
                System.out.println("key=" + k.val);
                System.out.println("child count : " + v.size());
                v.forEach(e -> {
                    System.out.print(e.val + " ");
                });
                System.out.println();
            }
            
        });
    }

    static class Employee {
        public int val;
        public ArrayList<Employee> sub;

        public Employee() {
            sub = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public Employee(int val) {
            this.val = val;
            this.sub = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee $val=" + val + ", sub=" + sub + "#";
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
key=6
child count : 3
5 8 1 
key=4
child count : 7
3 6 2 4 5 8 1 
key=3
child count : 2
2 4
```